# Best way to extract data from Azure Data Lake to SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, data-extraction

I am looking for a best programmatic way to extract data from Azure Data Lake to MSSQL database, which is installed on a VM within Azure.

Currently I am considering following options:

- [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
- SSIS ([Using Azure Data Lake Store Connection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/azure-data-lake-store-connection-manager))
- User-Defined Outputter [Example1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621334.aspx), [Example2](https://gist.github.com/serri588/e41a3da38f55d8ebc047cd1b953c0ad3)
- Custom C# code that reads Azure Data Lake data and inserts it into SQL Server DB

Any other good ways I am missing?

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment extraction from ADLA directly to SQL Server is still not available - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13745238-support-output-to-sql-and-sql-dw

Comment: Hi @VictorF, I'm guessing they mean Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) rather than Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA)?

Comment: What version of SQL? What format are the files in?

Comment: @GregGalloway It's SQL Server 2016 and it's inside a ADLA database table (but it can be a simple .csv stored on ADLS if it will be more convenient)

Comment: @VictorF I was thinking that since you had SQL 2016 you could use Polybase. But I don't believe Polybase in SQL 2016 supports Azure Data Lake Store as a source. So nevermind that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql For what it's worth, I think your list of options is good.

Answer (score 1):

Data factory v2 (currently in public preview), also supports [hosting SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure) to give you a data factory AND ssis option.

And not necessarily a good idea for many scenarios, but Azure Logic Apps has both a [data lake store connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatalake/) and [SQL Server connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure), which could be useful in scenarios such as writing lots of small files on a schedule or trigger.

You also may not need to go full on c# and instead use PowerShell, there are powershell modules for both data lake store and sql server.